# cassandra - multitenancy : trying to create 4000 keyspaces, fails at 700

Tags: cassandra, jrubyonrails

Environment: Jruby, Rails 2.3.8, cassandra-gem, cassandra 1.1

We are creating a new keyspace per tenant in our cassandra backed multi-tenant application. While testing we found Cassandra fail

```
at 400 keyspaces on a 8GB RAM machine, 7200 RPM disk
at 700 keyspaces on a 24 GB RAM machine, 7200 RPM disk
```

Also found it run painfully slow after 100 or so keyspaces. It took ~7 hours to create 700 keyspaces and consumed ~35GB of disk space with no data entered into it.

We then switched our testing to validate the maximum number of column families in a keyspace, hoping to use `<tenant id>_<columnfamily name>` named CFs. This test also failed at ~3000 CFs.

Now we are looking at `<tenant_id>_<key>` for row keys and use the same CFs for all tenants. This is based on the notes at https://github.com/rantav/hector/wiki/Virtual-Keyspaces.

The question is, `would prepending tenant_id to key work for the following CF, given the key validation class is LongType?`.

```
ColumnFamily: monthly_unique_user_counts
"count of unique users per month"
  Key Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType
  Default column value validator: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType
  Columns sorted by: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType
  Row cache size / save period in seconds / keys to save : 0.0/0/all
  Row Cache Provider: org.apache.cassandra.cache.ConcurrentLinkedHashCacheProvider
  Key cache size / save period in seconds: 200000.0/14400
```

For a few other CFs, the Key Validation Class is

```
Key Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType
```

Would the `<tenant_id>_<key>` concept work in that CF?.